# Does pseudo-destructor-name make a sense for non-class and non-enum type?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

There is a quote from 5.2.4/1 of [N3797](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf), the C++14 final working draft:

> The use of a pseudo-destructor-name after a dot . or arrow -> operator
>   represents the destructor **for the non-class type** denoted by type-name
>   or decltype-specifier.

---

**Question**

- For what type we can consider `pseudo-destructor-name`, is it *enum-type* only?

Comment: 5.2.4 of what document?

Comment: I'm with @jbruni. Can you give us a decent link, to check the context of this reference.

Comment: Does this help? http://cprogrammers.blogspot.com/2005/11/c-programming-pseudo-destructors.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Is it *enum-type* only?**

No, the *pseudo-destructor-call* is valid on **any** type.

---

**But, what about... this?**

```
enum Foo : int { ... };
typedef int Bar;

Foo a; a.~Foo ();         // (1), legal
int b; b.~Bar ();         // (2), legal
int c; c.~decltype(c) (); // (3), legal


int d; d.~int ();         // (4), ill-formed... why?
```

It seems odd that *(4)* is ill-formed, all others are legal; isn't the intent to invoke a *psuedo-constructor-call* on an `int` in all cases?

It seems quite obvious that we are not using a *decltype-specifier* in neither *(3)* or *(4)*, so the question is:

- What is a *type-name*, and how does its definition affect the previously written snippet?

---

The definition of *type-name* is available at `[dcl.type.simple]p1`, and says that a *type-name* is;

- a *class-name*, or;
- an *enum-name*, or;
- a *typedef-name*, or;
- a *simple-template-id*.

Notice that the above list does not include *fundamental types*, and this is why *(4)* is ill-formed, and *(3)* isn't; even though we are invoking a *pseudo-destructor-call* on an `int` in both cases.

`int` is the name of a type, but it isn't a *type-name*.

Answer (score 0):

Like the text says, it's for all types, except for class types. In those rare cases where you need to explicitly call the destructor, the possibility of a pseudo-destructor call makes it possible to not worry about whether the type is a class type. If it's a class type, you'll call the actual destructor; it won't be a pseudo-destructor call. If it's not a class type, the expression is safe and has no effect.