# Are there language constructs that are valid for type-name but not for fundamental types?

Tags: c++

I noticed that pseudo destructor call is valid when a *type-name* is used but not when a fundamental type is used.

```
typedef int BType;
int b;
b.~BType();   // Legal
b.~int();     // Not legal
```

An explanation for the above can be found at [an answer to another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24000642/434551).

Definition of *type-name*, from the C++11 Standard:

> **7.1.6.2 Simple type specifiers, p1**
>
> ```
> type-name:  
>    class-name   
>    enum-name  
>    typedef-name  
>    simple-template-id
> ```

Are there any other language constructs that are valid when the type specifier is a *type-name* but not valid when it is a fundamental type even when the *type-name* represents a fundamental type, as shown above?

Comment: A temporary object expression: `T{}` is valid, but `int[5]{}` is not. (But `int[5]` isn't a fundamental type.)

Comment: I don't know if this is in your parameters, but you can redefine a type-name in an interior scope or namespace. `{using T = int;}` ok / `{using int = T;}` not.

Comment: @rici, It is not what I was thinking. Here, `T` is being defined. We know that fundamental types can't be re-defined. Let me refine my question.

Comment: Well, it could be already defined as a type. But I understand that it is not exactly what you're expecting as an answer.

Comment: Just so people can grok what we're talking about, C+11 §7.1.6.2/1 defines a *type-name* as either a *class-name*, an *enum-name*, a *typedef-name* or a *simple-template-id*. A pseudo destructor call accepts also a *decltype-specifier*. Which means that this is OK: `int i; i.~decltype(i)();`. Which is a general way to write a destructor call regardless of type. Pretty neat. :)

Comment: I'm not aware of more (reasonable) special cases. But considering that the reason keywords like `int` aren't permitted is that they're keywords, there might just be something lurking there.

Comment: after that typedef, `void f() { int BType; }` is valid, whereas `void f() { int int; }` is not

Comment: @M.M, I am specifically looking for use of type specifiers, not other names.

Comment: Please clarify your question, see my comments in the answer below, it seems there is a couple of ways to interpret your question. Also you can see my deleted answer and see if my original interpretation is correct and then I can undelete my answer.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour, thanks for the prod. I updated the question.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour, yes, of course.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour, that's awesome. It' good to spread the wealth around, even pretend internet wealth :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not think you will find any other cases. If we look at the draft C++ standard *Annex A Grammar summary* we can see the only other locations in the grammar where *type-name* shows up are:

```
nested-name-specifier:
  ::
  type-name ::
  namespace-name ::
  decltype-specifier ::
  nested-name-specifier identifier ::
  nested-name-specifier templateopt simple-template-id ::
```

and:

```
simple-type-specifier:
  nested-name-specifieropt type-name
  [...]
```

Neither of which provide a similar opportunity that we get with the pseduo-destructor which has the following grammar:

```
pseudo-destructor-name:
  nested-name-specifieropt type-name :: ~ type-name
  nested-name-specifier template simple-template-id :: ~ type-name
  nested-name-specifieropt~ type-name
  ~ decltype-specifier
```

and is covered in section `5.2.4` [expr.pseudo] which provides for the behavior we see:

> The use of a pseudo-destructor-name after a dot . or arrow -> operator
>   represents the destructor for the non-class type denoted by type-name
>   or decltype-specifier. The result shall only be used as the operand
>   for the function call operator (), and the result of such a call has
>   type void. The only effect is the evaluation of the postfix-expression
>   before the dot or arrow.

on the other hand we can see the rules for nested-name-specifier in section `3.4.3` *[basic.lookup.qual]* forbid such a case:

> The name of a class or namespace member or enumerator can be referred
>   to after the :: scope resolution operator (5.1) applied to a
>   nested-name-specifier that denotes its class, namespace, or
>   enumeration. If a :: scope resolution operator in a
>   nested-name-specifier is not preceded by a decltype-specifier, lookup
>   of the name preceding that :: considers only namespaces, types, and
>   templates whose specializations are types. If the name found does not
>   designate a namespace or a class, enumeration, or dependent type, the
>   program is ill-formed

The simple-type-specifier case does not get us there either since fundamental types are already acceptable for this case.

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference when the return type of a function is a fundamental type or not:

```
struct X{};

template <class T> auto foo() {
  // one liner
  []() -> T { return T{}; }() = T{}; // invalid for T fundamental type

  // or more clear:
  auto get_t = []() -> T { return T{}; };
  get_t() = T{}; // invalid for T fundamental type
}

auto main() -> int {
  foo<X>();    // valid
  foo<int>();  // invalid
  return 0;
}
```

Without templates, to be even more clear:

```
struct X{};

auto ret_x() -> X { return X{}; }    
auto ret_int() -> int { return int{}; }


auto main() -> int {
  ret_x() = X{};     // valid
  ret_int() = int{}; // invalid
  return 0;
}
```

rvalues for fundamental types cannot be modified. This is clearly not the case for other types, as, for instance, a move operation must modify the temporary from which it moves (e.g. make the owning pointer nullptr)

Comment: I think what the OP meant to say was: *constructs that are valid when the type specifier is a type-name that is a fundamental type*

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour ..oh, I see. Should I delete the answer?

Comment: I am not sure, that is how I originally read it but now I can see how you read it differently. I don't think the question is as interesting if that is not the case. But the OP needs to clarify. Otherwise we have a trivial case of *nested-name-specifier*.

Comment: @bolov, I think you have the valid and invalid comments switched. It's an interesting case though it's not what I had in mind.